# Should I add 'Protocol 2' to my sshd_config?

Tags: ssh

I recently installed debian 11.3 in a VM for testing, and also installed SSH Server during the expert install.
And I saw that the default sshd_config file has no Protocol option set.
Then I read e.g. at https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config:

> Protocol:
> Specifies the protocol versions sshd(8) supports. The possible values are '1' and '2'. Multiple versions must be comma-separated. **The default is ''2,1''**. Note that the order of the protocol list does not indicate preference [...]

So question 1: Does this mean by default my ssh server is serving the old and insecure version 1??

If yes, then question 2: Should I add 'Protocol 2' to my sshd_config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New standard is ssh protocol version 2 | `SSH-2`.

You don't need to do anything on `debian 11` you are working with `SSH-2`

Don't need to set 2 for `SSH-2` or 1 for `SSH-1`
or `2,1` for `SSH-2` and `SSH-1` in the `sshd_config`

Run this in your terminal, if you have not set a port `-p` or a key `-i`:

`ssh -1 [USER]@[IP]`

Normal you will receive this:

`SSH protocol v.1 is no longer supported`

An this for SSH2, but you don't need it normally because it is the standard:

`ssh -2 [USER]@[IP]`

I think even if you try to set SSH1 and you restart the sshd without error it will not work/ not supported any more.

Check this too:

[How to check SSH protocol version on Linux](https://www.xmodulo.com/check-ssh-protocol-version-linux.html)

[History of SSH](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch01_05.htm)

[History of SSH](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ssh-the-secure/0596008953/ch01s05.html)

Comment: This is correct. I just added 'Protocol 1' to the server config, restarted and tried to 'ssh -1 <ip>' from a client. No connection possible! Looks like you cant get current sshd versions to use v1 anymore!?